# Idiomatic way to get the container type instead of element type in Julia?

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I want to implement the following behavior.

```
container_type(::Type{Vector{T}}) where T = Vector
container_type(::Type{Matrix{T}}) where T = Matrix
```

But, of course I do not want to hard-code every concrete type. For starters, I want to be able to programmatically do this for every subtype of `AbstractVector`. I tried the following.

```
container_type(::Type{V{T}}) where {V <: AbstractVector, T} = V
```

But, this results in a `TypeError` because type variables cannot be nested. My next guess is iterating over all the subtypes of `AbstractVector`. The following works for a limited subset of the subtypes of `AbstractVector`

```
for vec_type in nameof.(subtypes(AbstractVector))
    try
        @eval begin
            container_type(::Type{$(vec_type){T}}) where T = $(vec_type)
        end
    catch
        for (exc, bt) in current_exceptions()
            showerror(stderr, exc, bt)
        end
    end
end
```

The `try`-`catch` block is required because some of the types in `subtypes(AbstractVector)` are scoped by modules.

```
julia> subtypes(AbstractVector)
20-element Vector{Any}:
 AbstractRange
 Base.ExceptionStack
 Base.LogicalIndex
 Base.MethodList
 Base.ReinterpretArray{T, 1, S} where {T, S}
 Base.ReshapedArray{T, 1} where T
 BitVector (alias for BitArray{1})
 CartesianIndices{1, R} where R<:Tuple{OrdinalRange{Int64, Int64}}
 Core.Compiler.AbstractRange
 Core.Compiler.BitArray{1}
 Core.Compiler.ExceptionStack
 Core.Compiler.LinearIndices{1, R} where R<:Tuple{Core.Compiler.AbstractUnitRange{Int64}}
 Core.Compiler.MethodList
 DenseVector (alias for DenseArray{T, 1} where T)
 LinearIndices{1, R} where R<:Tuple{AbstractUnitRange{Int64}}
 PermutedDimsArray{T, 1} where T
 AbstractSparseVector (alias for SparseArrays.AbstractSparseArray{Tv, Ti, 1} where {Tv, Ti})
 SubArray{T, 1} where T
 Tables.EmptyVector
 Test.GenericArray{T, 1} where T
```

and `nameof` discards the module names altogether

```
julia> subtypes(AbstractVector) .|> nameof
20-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :AbstractRange
 :ExceptionStack
 :LogicalIndex
 :MethodList
 :ReinterpretArray
 :ReshapedArray
 :BitArray
 :CartesianIndices
 :AbstractRange
 :BitArray
 :ExceptionStack
 :LinearIndices
 :MethodList
 :DenseArray
 :LinearIndices
 :PermutedDimsArray
 :AbstractSparseArray
 :SubArray
 :EmptyVector
 :GenericArray
```

which is why they cannot be found in the `@eval` block.

I have been stuck at this point. How can I work around this error? Is there any other approach that might work better here?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to return from your `container_type` function? Are you returning a `Type`? A `Symbol` (`Symbol("Vector")`)? A `String` (`"Vector"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
ctype(::T) where T <:AbstractArray = T.name.wrapper
```

Now you can do:

```
julia> ctype(1:4)
UnitRange

julia> ctype([7,8,9])
Array
```

Note that `Vector` and `Matrix` are aliases to `Array` rather than types (aliases with different dimension parameters) so if you want to distinguish between the two you need to get the type directly.

```
ctype2(::T) where T <:AbstractVector = T
```